# initial multiple values in select fields

Tags: python, django

I have problem to initail multiple values in a select field

```
keyword=WorkerGenre.objects.filter(worker=customer.id)
keyword_list=[]
for k in keyword:
    keyword_list.append(k.genre) 
    print k.genre 

form=ChangeProfile(request.POST,initial={'keyword':keyword_list},)
```

It only initial one value in the multiple select field even I can see there are more than one value from

```
    print k.genre
```

can anyone help me here

Comment: is that how you really indented your code? is `form=...` in the correct position there? if that's really like that, you'll end up every time with the last value from `keyword_list`

Comment: what should i do for get all values, like you say it is only with the last value

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in keyword:
    keyword_list.append(k.genre) 
    print k.genre 

form=ChangeProfile(request.POST,initial={'keyword':keyword_list},)
```

Mind the indentation. If your `request.POST`contains a value for `keyword`, you'll lose your initial values.

Comment: sorry,I have form=.. in the same column as for.. like you did here.

Comment: I found my problem, i forgot to add 'keyword':keyword_list, in a other place when i initial the form,but thanks anyway :)